# Assigning row_number() as a column value over a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, lapply

I'm working with a list of dataframes. For each dataframe in the list, I want to create a new column called "rank" where the values equal the row number.

```
# Create test dataframe list

a <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
b <- c(12,8,9,5,6,18)
c <- c("K","J","L","M","N","O")

df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c,b))

df_list <- list(df1,df2)

# List manipulations

df_list_t <- lapply(df_list, cbind, rank = c("")) # create "rank" column

# Trying to assign rank value...

df_list  <- df_list %>% mutate(rank = row_number())

## Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
## no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Is there a way around this or another method I could use to get the same result? My end goal is that each dataframe in the list will have a "rank" column numbered 1 - nrows. Assume that some of the dataframes in the list will have different numbers of rows.

```
  c  b rank
1 L  9  1   
2 J  8  2   
3 N  6  3   
4 M  5  4   
5 O 18  5   
6 K 12  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` and `cbind` to assign rownumbers:

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) cbind(x, rank=seq_len(NROW((x)))))
#[[1]]
#  a  b rank
#1 A 12    1
#2 B  8    2
#3 C  9    3
#4 D  5    4
#5 E  6    5
#6 F 18    6
#
#[[2]]
#  c  b rank
#1 K 12    1
#2 J  8    2
#3 L  9    3
#4 M  5    4
#5 N  6    5
#6 O 18    6
```

Answer (score 3):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `map` to loop over the `list` and create the 'rank' column with `row_number()`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(df_list, ~ .x %>%
                  mutate(rank = row_number())
```